# Use delimiter on arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have a txt file that looks like this:

```
1, 0, 0, 1, 1
1, 1, 1, 1, 0 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0
```

I need to get the following 2d array output:

```
{1, 0, 0, 1, 1}
{1, 1, 1, 1, 0}
{0, 0, 1, 1, 1}
{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
{0, 0, 0, 1, 0}
```

Basically I need my output to be a `double DATA[][]` like this example

```
double [][] DATA = new double [][]{
    {1, 0, 0, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}
};
```

Any ideas of how to do this? Here's what I've tried:

```
ArrayList<String[]>  listOfLines = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String line = bufReader.readLine();
while (line != null) { 
    String[] fields = line.split(",");
    listOfLines.add(fields);
    line = bufReader.readLine();
    // System.out.println(line);
}
for (String[] DATA : listOfLines) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(DATA));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like instead of making an array of strings you could use the `Double.parseDouble(String x)` method instead. For example (untested, but you should get the idea):

```
while (line != null) {
    String[] fields = line.split(",");
    ArrayList<Double> parsedFields = new ArrayList<Double>();
    for (String x : fields) {
        parsedFields.add(Double.parseDouble(x));
    }
    line = bufReader.readLine();
    listOfLines.add(parsedFields); // you'll have to change listOfLines' type;
}
```

After doing this, if you're looking to create a traditional 2D array, first we want to figure out the dimensions of the array that we're making. Note: you'll probably want to include some sort of error checking (i.e. make sure that each row has the same number of values, empty, etc.). Knowing the array's dimensions, you'll just have to iterate through and put the values into the array, something like this:

```
int rows = listOfLines.size();
int cols = listOfLines.get(0).size(); // this will fail if there is nothing in listOfLines!

Double[][] output = new Double[rows][cols];
for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<cols; j++ {
        output[i][j] = listOfLines.get(i).get(j);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Patrick. It was very helpful. Finally my code worked!

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER TO MY QUESTION:

```
     BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("//C://...."));

       List<String> listOfLines = new ArrayList<>();
       String line;
       while ((line = bufReader.readLine()) != null) {
       listOfLines.add(line);
                }

        double[][] output = new double[listOfLines.size()][];

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfLines.size(); i++) {
        final String currentString = listOfLines.get(i);
        final String[] split = currentString.split(",");
        output[i] = new double[split.length];
        for (int j = 0; j < split.length; j++) {
        output[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(split[j]);
}
 }

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(output));
```